# How to override Dojo's xhrGet and xhrPost?

Tags: ajax, dojo

We are extensively using `Dojo'`s `xhrGet` and `xhrPost` in our application. This has been used across multiple `JavaScript` files. Now we need a uniform way in which we handle the exceptions that are returned from the server in case of an AJAX call. We don't want to handle this in all places where we are using `Dojo'`s `xhrGet` or `xhrPost`. Is it possible to do that without disturbing any of the existing code? For example, when some exception is sent from the server as part of the ajax response, I need to display some message in a consistent way across the application.

Could you please suggest me a solution for this? Kindly let me know if any more information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you look at the dojo/aspect or dojo/on ? You can define functions that get executed after a function was called (or before) with aspect.

Take a look at that:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/aspect.html#dojo-aspect-after

Why dont you create a custom xhrArgs class using dojo/declare that has the same error function for all his children ?

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/declare.html#dojo-base-declare

Lucian

Answer (score 2):

Use [IO Pipeline Topics](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/ioPipelineTopics) as I described in [Generic Loading Icon in Dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885230/generic-loading-icon-in-dojo/10895198#10895198) and you won't have to change your code at all.